# How to distinguish independent capacitors in an n-order circuit?

Tags: capacitor

[image: demonst]

As in the image above, the capacitors are said to be dependent, so it is a first-order circuit.

How do I tell if two capacitors in such circuit are dependent or independent so it is first-order but not second-order circuit?

Comment: " the capacitors are said to be dependent, so it is a first-order circuit" - in general, that's thinking backwards. You solve the circuit first, find it's order, and then decide if the capacitors were independent or not. In this case its easy - the capacitors are in parallel, so they are equivalent to a single capacitor, therefore the circuit behaves like a simple RC circuit - which is first order

Comment: @FrancoVS You should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a circuit, any closed loop of capacitors only, will decrease by 1 the number of independent capacitors.

Infact, if you know the voltage Vi(t) of n-1 capacitors, the voltage Vn(t) of capacitor n is automatically determined by Kirchoff Voltage Law around that loop.

The number of poles decreases by 1 as well.

---

In a circuit, any closed loop of capacitors and voltage sources will decrease by 1 the number of independent capacitors.

Example

In a circuit where we have a series of 2 capacitors and a voltage source, the number of independent capacitors is 1.